# Change database character set in an existing MediaWiki installation

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mediawiki

I have an existing Mediawiki installation, for which I suppose I chose the `MySQL 4.1/5.0 binary` option when installing.

Two years later, I'm having problems with Mediawiki's fulltext search on accented chars, and then would like to switch to `MySQL 4.1/5.0 UTF-8` to use MySQL's native UTF-8 support.

Is there a safe way to do this? I could obviously convert all tables to UTF-8 in a batch, but I suppose there are a few options in Mediawiki that need to be updated accordingly, and maybe a few caches / search indexes to rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The affected settings are [$wgDBmysql5](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgDBmysql5) and [$wgDBTableOptions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgDBTableOptions) (check the talk pages for some useful information). The scripts in the `maintenance` dir starting with `rebuild`, `refresh` or `update` can help in fixing caches and indexes. I wouldn't call it a safe way (I don't know of any), but worth a try after a full backup.